# How something came from nothing.

Tags: cosmology

I am not sure whether I am asking this question at the right site of Stack Exchange.

If one thinks of a time when there was nothing in this void (I would not even say “in this universe” because the thought of “visualising as to what was there, when there was no universe” becomes sort of unimaginable) how something came from nothing?

Comment: If it will vanish to nothing there is no problem in **that**.

Comment: For Something to vanish is no problem but something to come in to existence is a problem ans hence this question. So where was the starting point? How that starting "instance" came into existence?

Comment: Actually, for something to vanish entirely without a trace is just as much a problem as for something to come into existence out of nothing.

Comment: You are right. After existence, the problem is from where it came and after vanishing the problem is where did it go and what remained in its place?

Comment: Nothing comes from nothing.

Comment: Nothing comes from nothing. But it is inescapable that something (Whatever that we have today) came from nothing. In that case is it that “nothing or lack of all”  is inconceivable in our mind  and that Nothing = God?

Comment: Why is there  something rather than nothing? This question was made 5 or more times in this site. Why one more?

Comment: Is there any chance I might be able to persuade you to specify this a bit further, maybe share a little more about the context and motivations of the concern here? (What might you have been reading or studying that has made this an urgent or important question? What have you found out so far? What are you expecting in an answer?)

Comment: "But it is inescapable that something (Whatever that we have today) came from nothing." - Wrong. Nothing comes from nothing, but something isn't nothing. Also, if "Nothing = God" then God doesn't exist. (I use nothing as empty set, so for me it's easily understandable. And something as nonempty set.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem of [Nothingness](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/), and as part of that the question of how "something arises from nothing" is a perfectly philosophical question by any measure. It's even generated a [recent](http://artsbeat.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/03/13/worlds-in-collision-after-tangle-over-physicists-book-philosophers-invitation-to-a-debate-is-withdrawn/) [amount](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/25/books/review/a-universe-from-nothing-by-lawrence-m-krauss.html) of [controversy](http://www.npr.org/blogs/13.7/2012/05/01/151752815/blackboard-rumble-why-are-physicists-hating-on-philosophy-and-philosophers) on the nature of nothingness itself, and the origins of both physical matter and the laws governing it.

In part, it's a question without an answer, and some might say it's impossible to answer the question to begin with. Others might use it [to argue for the existence of a Creator](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cosmological-argument/), but at least one religion reverses the distinctive question to argue that the actual mystery is [how "*nothing* could possibly arise from *something*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzimtzum).